# ReactJS - render with default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I rerender component with state from `getInitialState()`?

For example: https://jsbin.com/pajapoyipo/edit?html,output

In example code I click on the button, component Button change state and button is Yellow - its work, but when I click on another button I would like to clicked the button was yellow (its work), and the old button changed state and color to red (it doesn't work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid stuff like this:

```
childState.setState({klasa: "yellow"});
```

You should not be setting child state from the parent. State is internal to a component, it should only be changed by itself. Instead, the parent can re-render the child with different props.

If you want only one button to be active, then you have to have some piece of state that will only permit a single active button. Since children can't know about their fellow siblings, this piece of state must reside in the parent. I've called it `activeBtn`. If `activeBtn` is 1, then the first button appears yellow. This piece of state in the parent corresponds to the boolean property `active` in child. I've also defined a click handler in the parent to change the state. This click handler is passed down to each child as a prop.

If that doesn't make sense, the modified code should serve as a better explanation:
https://jsbin.com/filasisemu/1/edit?html,output